# In a MVVM WPF app how can I show a validation error for a button?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a view which is bound to a view model having a number of properties. Some of the properties are bound directly to controls like text boxes. For these I set a validation template which shows a red border with corner arrow which shows the errors for the property in a tool tip.

Other properties are set by forms which are opened in response to clicking buttons. For example I have button labeled "Click to edit duration" which pops up form to edit the `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties. The button is bound to a command in the view model which pops up the form.

The view model implements `INotifyDataErrorInfo` so for the controls which are bound directly to properties I can just attach error messages to the properties they are bound to and raise the `ErrorsChanged` event.

What I want is if the start and end dates are not properly set then a red border and tool tip is applied to the button. Attaching errors to `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties won't work because the button is not bound to these properties.

Comment: Why don't you just control the input text from the `StartDate` and `EndDate` form ? Until the dates aren't right dont let the user continue.

Answer (score 0):

I had done the same thing in an application where there is an additional section of data that needs to be completed to continue. The way I was able to make the button have a validation error was by using a Tag like this:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="{DynamicResource resEnterSecureInformation}" Width="200" Command="{Binding PrimaryApplicant.SecureInformation.OpenSecureInformationWindowCommand}" Tag="{Binding PrimaryApplicant.SecureInformationComplete, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"></Button>
```

I also had a style in my app.xaml to add the red outline and a tooltip when an error was set:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Red"  BorderThickness="1" >
                                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

I did this to also not show the validation error when the button was disabled (no need showing the user something they can't go into and fix)

Hope this helps